# wordpress mobile applications with phonegap

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress

I'm reading this tutorial and I'm having some problems with the examples... I tried to run the examples in localhost but I'm encountering with some errors and really don't know what could it be. I should be getting the first post of WP, but instead of that I'm getting this error **Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined**. Any sugestions??? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<header>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(url,target_div) {
var URL = url
jQuery.ajax({
url: URL,
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
jQuery(target_div).html(data.post.content);
}
});
}
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#title").html("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
varurl = "http://localhost/phonegap/?json=get_post&dev=1&p=1";
vartarget_div = "#contents";
readSinglePost(url, target_div);
}); 
</script>

</header>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="title"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "varurl =" should have a space to be "var url =" and same with "vartarget_div =" should be "var target_div =" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change a code as `var url` not `varurl` and `var target_div` not 'vartarget_div'. Give space to keyword var and the variable.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#title").html("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
var url = "http://localhost/phonegap/?json=get_post&dev=1&p=1";
var target_div = "#contents";
readSinglePost(url, target_div);
});
```